# Copying swift string to fixed size char[][]

Tags: swift, macos

I have a C struct like this.

```
struct someStruct {
char path[10][MAXPATHLEN];
};
```

I'd like to copy a list of Swift strings into the char[10][] array.

For me it's very challenging to handle c two-dimensional char array in Swift. Could anyone share some code which can work with Swift 5? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C Arrays are imported to Swift as tuples. Here we have a two-dimensional C array, which becomes a nested tuple in Swift:

```
public struct someStruct {

    public var path: (
        (Int8, ...,  Int8),
        (Int8, ...,  Int8),
        ...
        (Int8, ...,  Int8)
    )
}
```

There is no really “nice” solution that I am aware of, but using the fact that Swift preserves the memory layout of imported C structures ([source](https://forums.swift.org/t/mapping-c-semantics-to-swift/2688/6)), one can achive the goal with some pointer magic:

```
var s = someStruct()

let totalSize = MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: s.path)
let itemSize = MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: s.path.0)
let numItems = totalSize / itemSize

withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &s.path) {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: Int8.self, capacity: totalSize) { ptr in
        for i in 0..<numItems {
            let itemPtr = ptr + i * itemSize
            strlcpy(itemPtr, "String \(i)", itemSize)
        }
        print(ptr)
    }
}
```

`ptr` is a pointer to `s.path`, and `itemPtr` is pointer to `s.path[i]`. `strlcpy` copies the string, here we use the fact that one can pass a Swift string directly to a C function taking a `const char*` argument (and a temporary null-terminated UTF-8 representation is created automatically).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your wonderful tip. It really saves my life!

Answer (score 0):

I strongly encourage you to use some kind of helper methods.

**Example:**

```
/* writes str to someStruct instance at index */
void writePathToStruct(struct someStruct* s, size_t index, const char* str) {
    assert(index < 10 && "Specified index is out of bounds");
    strcpy(s->path[index], str);
}
```

Now, when calling this function, filling the array looks much cleaner:

```
var someStructInstance = someStruct()
let pathIndex: Int = 3
let path = "/dev/sda1"
let encoding = String.Encoding.ascii

withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &someStructInstance) { pointer -> Void in
    writePathToStruct(pointer, pathIndex, path.cString(using: encoding)!)
}
```

By design, tuples can not be accessed by variable index. Reading statically can thus be done without a helper function.

```
let pathRead = withUnsafeBytes(of: &someStructInstance.path.3) { pointer -> String? in
    return String(cString: pointer.baseAddress!.assumingMemoryBound(to: CChar.self), encoding: encoding)
}

print(pathRead ?? "<Empty path>")
```

However, I assume you will definitely have to read the array with a dynamic index.
In that case, I encourage you to use a helper method as well:

```
const char* readPathFromStruct(const struct someStruct* s, size_t index) {
    assert(index < 10 && "Specified index is out of bounds");
    return s->path[index];
}
```

which will result in a much cleaner Swift code:

```
pathRead = withUnsafePointer(to: &someStructInstance) { pointer -> String? in
    return String(cString: readPathFromStruct(pointer, 3), encoding: encoding)
}
```